# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope with SDK 19 in android studio

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-ksoap2, soap-serialization

hello i m using android studio this error generate and crash application in only sdk version 19. i did not found the reason .i search so many things but not found proper way to resolve this.

> Log Show as below

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)                            
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)      
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)   
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)         
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)                        
                                                        atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope
                                                        at com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.User_Setup_Service.User_Setup_Service.ReadMultiple(User_Setup_Service.java:241)
                                                        at com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.User_Setup_Service.User_Setup_Service$3.doInBackground(User_Setup_Service.java:223)
                                                        at com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.User_Setup_Service.User_Setup_Service$3.doInBackground(User_Setup_Service.java:216)
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope belong from external library folder

Comment: Is this happening with release build?

Comment: no it happen in debug mode